# Monitor cpu usage per process

Tags: monitoring, perfmon, process-monitoring

I would like to monitor CPU usage of all processes over time. By all processes I mean being able to view each process' CPU usage separately. I'd like to see the results as a graph and I prefer Perfmon, but I'm open to other tools.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [History of CPU usage for all processes](https://superuser.com/questions/609529/history-of-cpu-usage-for-all-processes)

Comment: I like typeperf for this and log to a CSV.  Use Excel to visualise it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Perfmon, you need to add a counter for process > % Processor time and select all instances.

In perfmon, there's a '+' icon to add counters. Find the process group in there and expand it. Select your desired counters (I'd recommend % Processor Time) and then select all instances in the instance box.

That'll give you a graph of all processes.
[image: Graph]

---

*Bonus*
If you need to get really specific, you can try [Process Explorer from SysInternals](https://live.sysinternals.com). It will give you similar to what Task Manager gives you, but you can select processes and create on-the-fly graphs of their CPU usage by right clicking a process, selecting properties, and then the Performance Graph tab.

Comment: This helped me. Thanks!