# Log Short Burst CPU Usage History Per Process in Windows

Tags: windows-7, display, cpu, process, logging

Brief:

I want to measure CPU usage of lossless audio compression in Windows. So, I create a batch file to run few codec and want to measure CPU usage of codec from launch until terminated, respectively. The codec run in short burst.

What I need:

- CPU process log/ history per process per unit of time.
- CPU process log/ history that can be exported to csv or similar.
- Not losing any single piece of burst time.

What I have tried:

- performance monitor = not applicable since perfmon only shows the process, not the program.
- sysinternal process monitor = great! but, it can't export CPU usage. it has very nice graph in process activity summary, but I have to plot my self.
- typeperf = nice, filtering process by name. but still too slow.

Thank you.

## update:

temporary solved by using typeperf:

```
typeperf "\Process(MAC)\% Processor Time"
```

Still figuring out to export to csv and set interval sampling.

## update2:

sysinternal process monitor by using graph tooltip to get CPU level.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/453909/log-cpu-by-process-over-time << like this, but need to export the graph.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

sysinternal process monitor by using graph tooltip to get CPU level.