# ADB-like thing for Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, freeze, debug, windbg

My actual aim is to find out what causes freezes occurring on a HP ProBook 450 G3 about once in a week (no reaction to any keystrokes except power button; however there is obvious activity, and the cooler actually becomes more active than on average). But I realize that in this form the question is hopelessly general, there might be dozens of very different reasons. So I decided to ask specifically whether there is some tool that I could use to peek inside the system - find out which processes are running, etc.

If it would be, say, an android tablet, I would know what to try: connect it via usb to a healthy computer and run adb; if the device is visible, I could then use logcat.

So my question is only this: is there some tool similar to adb that would work between, say, two Windows systems?

One related question I found here is [Using WinDbg to "break into" a badly hung kernel crash and see what's gone on?](https://superuser.com/q/1546505/308428); it has no answer but inside the question itself WinDbg is mentioned. If I understand correctly this would not help here, since WinDbg is installed and run on the same machine. Or is there a way to use WinDbg as a debug bridge between two machines?

Another related question is [How to find the culprit that freeze windows 10 when task manager is also frozen (till windows unfreezes)?](https://superuser.com/q/1461710/308428), it has one answer but this would not help me either - it suggests something like running Task Manager all the time, i. e. does not involve other computer, and would be impractical for freezes that occur very infrequently.

Comment: The most equivalent thing is your favorite development environment’s remote debugger. Visual Studio offers the [Visual Studio remote debugger](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2019). It does not deal with the kernel though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on what you're looking to do:

#### Userspace — If the OS is alive but video output is stuck

ADB still generally requires the target device to have a working OS – such things as `adb shell` or `adb logcat` really just connect to a special app that lets you inspect other app-related things.

Similarly, if your Windows OS is still able to receive network connections and start new processes, you have several services which can provide standard command-line access:

- SSH – [OpenSSH](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_overview) comes by default with recent Windows 10 versions and is easy to enable. (For older versions, [Bitvise WinSSHD](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server) is the least annoying alternative.) You can connect using the `ssh` command or using PuTTY.
- PowerShell has [PS-Remoting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting?view=powershell-7), which is a bit more cumbersome to set up and generally requires another Windows system to connect.
- There are also various semi-legacy DCOM RPC interfaces which let you run list processes on a remote system (`qprocess /server:<target>` or `tasklist /s <target>`) or access the Event Log (eventvwr.msc has "Connect to another computer") or various other management tasks.

(There is of course the graphical [Remote Desktop](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-allow-access), but due to the way it works – by *detaching* the entire desktop from the GPU when you connect via RDP – it's probably not a good debugging tool in your situation.

On the other hand, there's also a hidden shortcut <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> which attempts to reset the GPU driver in case that's the only issue.)

#### Kernelspace — If you're certain that the OS is completely hung

If the OS is completely wedged, remote kernel debugging is not a new thing. (It's an integral part of driver development, I would assume.) I have no experience with this whatsoever, but see [this section on Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/setting-up-kernel-mode-debugging-in-windbg--cdb--or-ntsd) for various ways to attach a debugger running on a second system to your OS.

(For example, the linked post makes a guess that FireWire (IEEE 1394) – which once was a more powerful competitor to USB – could be abused for this through its DMA support. And indeed, Windows has for a long time [supported](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/setting-up-kernel-mode-debugging-in-windbg--cdb--or-ntsd) 1394 debugging connections, although this was removed recently as the hardware support is getting rare.)

It seems from the website that the preferred method is [via Ethernet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/setting-up-a-network-debugging-connection-automatically), as long as the driver on the debugged system supports this function. Other methods listed on that site are serial (if you had a desktop PC with a "COM1" pin header) or USB (which requires a specially wired cable).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to be THE answer! Is not it strange that this thing seems to be not so widely known? At least I can say for sure not even nearly as widely as ADB.

Comment: The difference is that ADB is also used for debugging regular apps, it's the one-stop shop for all Android development so everybody uses it. Whereas on PCs, most apps are debugged locally; shell access and file transfer are done using purpose-built tools (such as SSH); and poking around in the OS kernel is very rare in comparison.

Comment: A much better example would be UART or JTAG access – for example, did you know that the headphone jack on some Android phones can double as a serial-port debug connection if you have a special cable? I'd say _that's_ the equivalent of Windows kernel-mode debugging.

Comment: And alternatively (which I forgot to cover), if you're looking for something closer to ADB, then the answer for Windows would be ordinary CLI access via SSH or PS-Remoting, even Windows Remote Desktop.

Comment: Could you please add this information, maybe even in a separate answer? Would not this require some actions from the target side first? What is the way to have it readily available all the time so that I can start using it when the system is already frozen?

Comment: I've added some information; my primary choice would be SSH, which is nearly universal for CLI remote connections (it's basically the PC equivalent of `adb shell`) and even for file transfer (using SFTP). The service can be just left running the whole time. Though, if the system is _actually_ frozen, all of this won't help much -- but e.g. on BSD or Linux there can be a huge difference between "GUI/console unresponsive" and "OS frozen", with SSH still working in the former case.

Comment: Great! Wish I could upvote once more. As I said, there is a chance that it is alive, although unresponsive, there are signs of ongoing processor activity.